# Replicating uploadTempFiles and getTempFile for SurveyJS in PHP

Tags: php, surveyjs

I am an experienced PHP and Javascript developer but implementing SurveyJS for the first time. I am trying to program and emulate the uploadTempFile and getTempFiles which SurveyJS graciously offer as a temporary solution from their own website.

Unfortunately, whilst I can imagine what they are trying to do, I am having difficulty in getting exactly the right API file configuration. Someone must have already solved this one and I would be grateful for a PHP code example.

My next task will be to implement TinyMCE or CKEditor on a comment or text area ....